# Unity 3D Shader Doesn't appear on VR mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, save, load, shader

We have two scene, in one scene we create level design and mechanics for VR in runtime, and other scene we use SteamVR for VR mode. Shader show up in editor scene but doesn't work in VR scene.

[image]

[image]

Thank you for your answers,

Comment: Does the scene maybe automatically change something in the Render pipeline settings?

Comment: No, I guessed that was an unsupported shader for our unity version but it was actually a save load problem due to our save load system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was a save load problem. We use 3th party asset from unity asset store (Runtime Save & Load) and SceneAssetLibrary.asset that hold scene asset references was overwritten when worked on scene. So we revert that file thus it worked again.